# Intellij IDEA 11.0.2, set tab size for custom file type?

Tags: tabs, intellij-idea

I'm using a fully licensed version of Idea.

I just created a custom file type for *.jade files.  Generally, I use a 4-space tab-size, but for *.jade files, I want to use a 2-space size.

That's it.  I don't want a work around.  I want to be able to set a specific tab size for only *.jade files.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_style.html

says: "...tab and indent size can be specified per file type."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to specify indent settings separately for custom file types right now. Such functionality is provided by the language specific plug-ins (even some language plug-ins do not allow to set custom indents and use settings from the General tab).

There is already a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-1889) submitted 7 years ago and with zero votes. Feel free to vote.